# Can someone explain useRef in commoners please?

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal the loads a table, I am Forwarding the ref from my app compnent to my spreadsheet component, every time the spreadsheet renders, it renders a copy of the spreadsheet, over and over and over. Ie, first render is worksheet 3,4. Close the modal out, open again, worksheet 5,6 and so on. I would appreciate any guidance on this.

I think this is because the component is rerendered on modal close. I am not sure.

I have tried loading the modal in both the spreadsheet and app component, and get the same results. I have also turned off strict mode, I read on react docs, that strict mode renders components twice if you functions arent pure, but ignores in production.

```
<Modal ref={ref}></Modal>
      <Spreadsheet ref={ref} license={license}>
     
        <Worksheet data={worksheet1.data} columns={worksheet1.columns}  minDimensions={worksheet1.minDimensions}/>
        <Worksheet data={worksheet2.data} columns={worksheet2.columns} validations={worksheet2.validations}/>
        
     </Spreadsheet>
```